# Sitecore Show parent and child items correctly using Nested Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

In the sitecore I have following structure:

> - Europe
>
>   - Germany
>   - France
>   - Sweden
> - Asia
>
>   - China
>   - Thailand
> - Middle East
>
>   - U.A.E
>   - Iran

I am using Nested repeater to show this structure in Asp.net

```csharp
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repSubsidiaryList">
<ItemTemplate>
<li>
 <%# Helper.Field(Container.DataItem as Item, "Short Title)%> 
   <asp:Repeater ID="InnerRepeater" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <li>
        <%# Helper.Field(Container.DataItem as Item, "Name")%>
       </li>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is Code behind:

```
List<Item> _countryNameItems = new List<Item>(); 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the item Subsidaries in sitecore 
    Item mainSubsidiaryFolderItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Settings.GetSetting("SubsidariesFolder"));

    _countryNameItems = mainSubsidiaryFolderItem.Axes.GetDescendants().Where(p => p.TemplateName == "Subsidiary").ToList();

    // binding Subsidiary Folder to a repeater
    repSubsidiaryList.DataSource = mainSubsidiaryFolderItem.GetChildren();
    repSubsidiaryList.DataBind();
}

private void repSubsidiaryList_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
    InnerRepeater = (Repeater) item.FindControl("InnerRepeater");
    InnerRepeater.DataSource = _countryNameItems;
    InnerRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

I am getting the results like this:

> - Europe
>
>   - Germany
>   - France
>   - Sweden
>   - China
>   - Thailand
>   - U.A.E
>   - Iran
> - Asia
>
>   - Germany
>   - France
>   - Sweden
>   - China
>   - Thailand
>   - U.A.E
>   - Iran
> - Middle East
>
>   - Germany
>   - France
>   - Sweden
>   - China
>   - Thailand
>   - U.A.E
>   - Iran

**I don't know how to get the currentItem and then bind the data.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner repeater is always datasourced to `_countryNameItems`. Replacing the `ItemDataBound` method with this should help:

```
private void repSubsidiaryList_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   // Cast the current dataitem to a Sitecore item
   Item item = (Item)e.Item.DataItem; 
   Repeater innerRpt = (Repeater) e.Item.FindControl("InnerRepeater");      
   // bind the inner repeater to the children of the sitecore item
   innerRpt.DataSource = item.Children; 
   innerRpt.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not that experienced with sitecore, but you are basically doing things wrong here.

You are setting the same `List<Item>`, i.e, `_countryNameItems` to each of your repeater. So you ideally need to pull different `List<Item>` inside the `ItemDatabound`. You could try something like this

Markup ( change the line above like innerRepeater like this )

```
<asp:Label ID="parentGroupLabel" runat="server" 
        Text='<%# Helper.Field(Container.DataItem as Item, "Short Title")%>'>
</asp:Label>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void repSubsidiaryList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
    var templateName = (Label) item.FindControl("parentGroupLabel");
    var InnerRepeater = (Repeater) item.FindControl("InnerRepeater");
    _countryNameItems = mainSubsidiaryFolderItem.Axes.GetDescendants().Where(p => p.TemplateName == templateName.Text).ToList();
    InnerRepeater.DataSource = _countryNameItems;
    InnerRepeater.DataBind();
}
```